# AspectJ Advice on Spring Security ProviderManager throws exception on startup

Tags: spring, spring-security, aspectj

Does anyone know why when I try to create an advice around the "doAuthentication" method of the Spring Security (v3.0) ProviderManager my application throws an exception on startup?

I am autowiring an instance of my spring authentication-manager bean into a controller and when the autowire is attempted my app fails to deploy.

Here is what my security context xml looks like...

```
...<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"> ...
```

Here is the pertinent part of my controller...

```
@Autowired
private ProviderManager authenticationManager;
```

and here is my advice declaration:

```
@After("execution(* org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(..)) && args(authentication)")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good question!!! Doh....

It's an exception trying to autowire the above controller with the ProviderManager... but, thanks to your post... I see what's happening... I'm trying to autowire that field and it's marked private... 

Welp, that leads me to more reading, I'm a bit know to the Aspect-Oriented Game... Thanks for your post.

Comment: Actually... it's weird, because I'm able to autowire it until I create an Aspect on that doAuthentication method of ProvderManager... here's the exception from my Tomcat logs..

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userActionController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:

Comment: private org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager com.redogre.epicgarbage.web.controllers.UserActionController.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: How are you applying the advice - are you using the AspectJ compiler?

Comment: I hope I'm answering this questions correctly, but I'm using the @Aspect annotation on my class and the @After annotation on my method that I would like to run after the doAuthenticate method is called by the security architecture. I just don't understand it, I have other advices in that file that work just fine, but it's just this one advice that fails my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure from the available information, but I'm guessing that you're using Spring AOP, which uses JDK dynamic proxies by default, so you are coming across the usual problem that the proxy does not retain the type of the original class (ProviderManager). The proxy will implement the interface AuthenticationManager, however. Try autowiring using this type and see if it works. Either that or you can enable class proxying which uses cglib instead of dynamic proxies. If you're using the Spring AOP namespace, you can set the *proxy-target-class* attribute to true.

Comment: Thanks, I think I missed that part in the spring docs. I appreciate your help.